# Beginner on Pointer Syntax in C

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I have a line of code that I can't understand. I am new to C programming and am going through some code that I have to sift through.

Can someone explain to me the following code:

```
short int *aux_status_register = ((short int *)(0x00001234));
```

What's confusing me is the code after the "`=`". Why is the "`*`" in a parentheses within the integer declaration as opposed to it being attached to the address (or what I think is the address that the pointer is pointing to)? Would things be different if the line of code was `(short int *0x00001234)`?

From what I got out of this line, `aux_status_register` is a pointer that points to an integer which is in hex: 0x1234. The contents that is stored in `aux_status_register` is stored in the  0x1234address location?

Please help. I really appreciate it...
Thanks.

Comment: address `0x00001234` is type casted to `short int *` which assumes that the value at the address is of  type `short int`

Answer (score 1):

The part in parentheses, `(short int *)`, is a type cast. It means that the number literal `(0x00001234)` will be treated as a pointer to a short integer at the address. If the `*` wasn't included in the parentheses `0x00001234` would just be cast to a `short int`.

Answer (score 1):

The `(short int *)` is a type casting which means the elements that follows it will be converted to a `short int` type pointer. So summarizing  what this statement do is assign the address `(0x00001234)` to the pointer `aux_status_register`, and it also determines that this is a address of `short int` kind.
You can check this by printing the value of your pointer :

```
printf("%p",aux_status_register);
```

which gives you:

```
0x1234
```

Answer (score 0):

A type name in parentheses is a typecast.
The type of the variable (on the left hand side of the equal sign) is "short integer pointer" and so the cast has to match: "(short int *)".

I don't think the cast is strictly necessary in this case, I'm pretty sure

```
short int *aux_status_register = 0x00001234;
```

would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**> short int *aux_status_register = ((short int *)(0x00001234));**
aux_status_register is a pointer to a short int. The number 0x1234 is being cast to a pointer to a short int. So the pointer aux_status_register now holds the address in memory 0x1234, which presumably contains the aux status.
This seems like a bad idea because it's a 32bit address, so on a 64bit machine you are losing half the address. But then, modern compilers being what they are, you are probably really getting 0x0000000000001234 put into aux_status_register.
To access the register (in order to check the aux status) you would use *aux_status_register which would tell you the value that is stored at memory location 0x1234.